# Extracting all Image tags from DIV using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working in Javascript. I want to Extract All the image tags inside a DIV using Javascript only and not JQuery or Regex etc. Can I do this ?? 
AnyHelp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
var imgs = document.images;
var src = [];
for( var i = imgs.length; i--; ){
src.push( img.src );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depence, what exactly you want(and which browser), but here is some code that should work very often.

here is how i would do it:

```
var imgNodes = document.getElemetById("DIVCONTAINER").getElementsByTagName("img");

for(var idx = 0; idx < imgNodes.length;idx++)
{
  alert(imgNodes[idx].src);
}
```

Code to Test you can find here.

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/SBjA8/1/</strike>

http://jsfiddle.net/SBjA8/2/

Comment: No alert in jsfiddle too

Comment: There was some problem with that fiddle. test() was always undefined..anyway I have modified it to this. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/SBjA8/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094):

```
var images = div.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Answer (score 0):

First do a

```
var divObj = document.getElementById('the div that contains the image tags')
```

, then

```
//this will give you a NodeCollection of img tags in this divand not an array
divObj.getElementsByTagName('IMG')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: I have alert divObj it shows [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: That is correct. You will get a reference to the div when you run document.getElementById('your div id'). If you are using an updated browser like FF or Chrome, just console.log(divObj) and you will see in the developer tools' console that divObj is the div you wanted to select and all of its properties.